# SQL Server UNION and offset primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to union two tables, and in the results, have a column of the second table be offset by the max value of that column in the first table.

Example: suppose I have two tables where both have the same columns:

TableA

```
 a | b | c
 1 | 1 | 1
 2 | 2 | 2
```

TableB

```
 a | b | c
 1 | 6 | 6
 2 | 7 | 7
```

I want to be able to perform something like a UNION ALL which results in:

Results

```
 a | b | c
 1 | 1 | 1
 2 | 2 | 2
 3 | 6 | 6
 4 | 7 | 7
```

By performing an actual UNION ALL my results are:

Results

```
 a | b | c
 1 | 1 | 1
 2 | 2 | 2
 1 | 6 | 6
 2 | 7 | 7
```

**UPDATE:** I would also like to put this into a VIEW, which is complicating it for me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: To be clear, you specifically want column 'a' of rows from tableB to have the maximum value of column 'a' in tableA added to them in the UNION ALL table?

Comment: Correct, but without updating tableB, and I would also like this to be a VIEW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the max `a` value from table A and add it to column `a` from table B.

```
select a,b,c from tblA
union all
select a+t.max_a,b,c from tblB 
cross join (select max(a) as max_a from tblA) t
```

Comment: This does exactly what I needed! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

does it value of column [a] for both table needs to follow original value ?

```
select a = row_number() over (order by a), b, c
from
(
    select a, b, c from tableA
    union all
    select a, b, c from tableB
) d
```

alternatively, use row_number() to generate a sequence for tableb

```
select  a = coalesce(a, max(a) over() + row_number() over(order by a)),
    b, c
from
(
    select  a, b, c
    from    tableA
    union all
    select  a = NULL, b, c
    from    tableB
) d
order by a
```